# Spring Security java config : intercept the wrong urls and redirect to an error page

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm woking on a spring web application lately, using spring security, hibernate and thymeleaf.

I opted for a no XML approach.

I want to intercept the wrong urls that the user might insert and redirect him to a custom error page( and not the default glassfish error page), as well as the 505 error (when there is a problem with the views ) so my question is, what to add and where ?

PS: 
i have a `@ControllerAdvice` controller